# What is the best way to store nested data in a python class?

Tags: python

I have a simple python program that is meant to do operations on C source code. So I extract the header files from the #include in the .c file and store them, take the function declarations from the .h files and store those too, and take the variables from the functions.

The problem is, how can I nest these into a class as well as keep them linked? 
i.e. .c files contain lists of .h files, .h files contain lists of function declarations, function declarations contains lists of variables.

So far all I've got is:

```
class C_File:
    file_count = 0

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        C_File.file_count += 1

    def headerFile(self, header_name, functions):
        self.header_name = header_name
        self.functions = []
        for x in functions:
            self.variables.append(x)
```

I'm not sure if dictionaries would be a better option? Or do I even need a class at all? (This is my first python program, I'm used to working in C)

Answer (score 0):

Make everything an object, and each object acts as a container for its sub-objects. When you instantiate a class, it's responsible for parsing its object to find its children.

So, you create a C_File, it iterates over the contents of the files and creates H_File objects. When you create an H_File, it iterates over its contents and creates Funcs. When you create a Func it iterates over its contents to create Vars. And so on.

For example:

```
class C_File(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.headers = []
        for header in self._get_headers(filename):
            self.headers.append(H_File(header))

class H_File(object):
    def __init__(self, header):
        self.funcs = []
        for func in self._get_funcs(header):
            self.funcs.append(Func(func))

class Func(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.vars = []
        for var in self._get_vars(func):
            self.vars.append(Var(var))
```

Then, your main program only has to loop over a list of filenames, creating C_Files:

```
def main():
    c_files = []
    for file in os.path.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
        c_files.append(C_File(file))
```

As each object is created it starts a chain of events that find all the children, grandchildren and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about keeping them as separate objects.